# Should Spring Boot Security 5 oauth2 not refresh expired Azure access tokens automatically if a refresh token is returned from Azure AD?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

Spring boot 2.3.9. Using app registration in Azure AD with OpendId connect flow (authz code).

My Spring security authentication object is getting populated with a proper access token and refresh token.

I pass along the access token to Azure Storage SDK call as a token credential in order to connect to Azure storage.

This works, until my access token expires and Azure storage replies back with a 401 Token lifetime expired.

Is Spring Security oauth2 implementation not supposed to handle this for me? And request new access token using the refresh token currently held in the authentication object?

Some code on how I load my oauth client and obtain an access token to call the storage API:

```
@Autowired
OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oauthClientService;

protected OAuth2AuthenticationToken getCurrentOauth2Authentication() {
    return (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}

public BlobServiceClient getBlobServiceClient() {

    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = getCurrentOauth2Authentication();
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = oauthClientService
            .loadAuthorizedClient(oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oauthToken.getName());

    BlobServiceClientBuilder bscb = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().retryOptions(new RequestRetryOptions())
            .httpLogOptions(new HttpLogOptions().setLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
                    .setAllowedHeaderNames(Set.of("x-ms-lease-id")).setAllowedQueryParamNames(Set.of("sv",
                            "delimiter", "marker", "prefix", "maxresults", "restype", "comp", "include")))
            .endpoint(appConfig.getAzStorageBaseUrl());

    Assert.notNull(client,
            "OauthClient cannot be null.");

    com.azure.core.credential.AccessToken at = new AccessToken(client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue(),
            OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(client.getAccessToken().getExpiresAt(), ZoneId.of("America/Toronto")));

    bscb.credential(request -> Mono.just(at));

    return bscb.buildClient();
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, when choosing to use a token for calling api(in azure ad,you need an azure ad app which assigned api permission to generate an access token, this token can be used to call specific api), you've accepted the feature about access token(have specific scope, limited expire time, etc.). If you set the rule generating new access token when the old one expired, it's more likely to make the token never expired. In my position, you can try to [rewrite the token policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes) to set a longer expired time.

Comment: If you insist on finding a way to refresh the access token automatically, could you pls add more details on how you generating access token?

Comment: I did mention in my original post... I do have an app registration in my Azure AD tenant and connect to it from my Spring Boot application using Spring security 5 oauth2 configuration. The spring authentication object does get populated with AD auth info. I obtain the oauth2client in spring using spring provided oauth2clientservice and get the oauthtoken from the loaded oauth2client. My az storage SDK calls work up until the access token expires. I was under the assumption Spring managed this for me and would post the refresh token for me to refresh the expired token.I will post some code.